# How to set numbers in mat-icon button in Angular material Design

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to set numbers in mat-icon button instead of other icons.but in my case when I set some other icons it's working but when I set numbers it's showing a blank button .

I tried to resolve but I could not find the problem .

app.component.html

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <button mat-mini-fab><mat-icon >1</mat-icon></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <button mat-mini-fab><mat-icon >2</mat-icon></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <button mat-mini-fab><mat-icon >3</mat-icon></button>
            </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
              <button mat-mini-fab><mat-icon >4</mat-icon></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone help me to fix it .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `mat-icon` :

`<button mat-mini-fab>1</button>`

Answer (score 3):

`MatIcon` will replace its content with an icon from the icon set you provide it (material icons by default) and shows nothing if it can't find any. For example if you have `<mat-icon>home<mat-icon>` it will show the home icon but if you have `<mat-icon>asd<mat-icon>` it won't show anything (You can find the list [here](https://material.io/tools/icons/)), same goes for numbers.

If you want a mini fab button with `1` in it just use  `<button mat-mini-fab>3</button>`
, no need to use `mat-icon`